# Converting dict values that are list of varying lengths into one list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I have data that was given as a `list` of dictionaries. The values of the dictionaries are `list` of `int` values of varying lengths.

```
[{'values': [876.0]},
 {'values': [823.0]},
 {'values': [828.0]},
 {'values': [838.0]},
 {'values': [779.0]},
 {'values': [804.0, 805.0, 738.0]},
 {'values': [756.0]},
 {'values': [772.0]},
 {'values': [802.0]},
 {'values': [812.0]},
 {'values': [746.0]},
 {'values': [772.0]},
 {'values': [834.0, 844.0]},
```

I would like to get all `dict` values into one `list` (named `rr_intervals` in my sample code).

```
[876.0, 823.0, 828.0, 838.0, 779.0, 804.0, 805.0, 738.0, 756.0, 772.0, 802.0, 812.0, 746.0, 772.0, 834.0, 844.0]
```

My solution below worked just fine, but it took a while with all the nested `for` loops. I was wondering whether there'd be a more elegant solution?

```
rr_intervals = []
for dictionary in rr_list:
    for key in dictionary:
        if len(dictionary[key]) == 1:
            rr_intervals.append(dictionary[key][0])
        elif len(dictionary[key]) > 1:
            for rr in dictionary[key]:
                rr_intervals.append(rr)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use *list comprehension*.

```
rr_intervals = [val for sub_dict in rr_list for val in sub_dict['values']] #rr_list is the list of dictionaries.
# [876.0, 823.0, 828.0, 838.0, 779.0, 804.0, 805.0, 738.0, 756.0, 772.0, 802.0, 812.0, 746.0, 772.0, 834.0, 844.0]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use **list comprehension** to achieve that in a pythonic way,

```
L = [{'values': [876.0]},
     {'values': [823.0]},
     {'values': [828.0]},
     {'values': [838.0]},
     {'values': [779.0]},
     {'values': [804.0, 805.0, 738.0]},
     {'values': [756.0]},
     {'values': [772.0]},
     {'values': [802.0]},
     {'values': [812.0]},
     {'values': [746.0]},
     {'values': [772.0]},
     {'values': [834.0, 844.0]}]

values = [num for d in L for key, value in d.items() for num in value]
print(values)
```

**Output:**

```
[876.0, 823.0, 828.0, 838.0, 779.0, 804.0, 805.0, 738.0, 756.0, 772.0, 802.0, 812.0, 746.0, 772.0, 834.0, 844.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it's "elegant":

```
result = []

for i in rr_list:
    result += i.get('values')
```

Output:

```
[876.0, 823.0, 828.0, 838.0, 779.0, 804.0, 805.0, 738.0, 756.0, 772.0, 802.0, 812.0, 746.0, 772.0, 834.0, 844.0]
```

Comment: +1. [Readability counts!](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/). If you make it so robust as to use `dict.get`, you should also pass it a default value that will not raise an exception, e.g. `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```py
rr_intervals = []
for dictionary in rr_list:
    for value in dictionary.values():
        rr_intervals.extend(value)
```