# Converting dict values that are list of varying lengths into one list, then adding that list to a Dataframe

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension

My question is a follow-up to [a question I asked last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60377899/converting-dict-values-that-are-list-of-varying-lengths-into-one-list).

I have data that was given as a `list` of dictionaries. The values of the dictionaries are `list` of `int` values of varying lengths. They're in a `pandas` `DataFrame` named `df_sim` (column name `rrintervals`)

```
startedat                   rrintervals
0   2020-02-27 15:06:35     [{'values': [727.0]}, {'values': [693.0, 688.0...
1   2020-02-27 15:06:22     [{'values': [1067.0]}, {'values': [921.0]}, {'...
2   2020-02-27 15:36:52     [{'values': [776.0]}, {'values': [826.0, 938.0..

IN:
print(df_sim.loc[0, "rrintervals"])

OUT:
[{'values': [727.0]}, {'values': [693.0, 688.0]}, {'values': [689.0]}, {'values': [699.0]}]
```

I would like to get all dict values in column `rrintervals` into one list and I want to store in a new column in `df_sim`, called `rr_list`.

```
startedat                   rrintervals                                           rr_list
0   2020-02-27 15:06:35     [{'values': [727.0]}, {'values': [693.0, 688.0...     [727.0, 693.0, 688.0...]
1   2020-02-27 15:06:22     [{'values': [1067.0]}, {'values': [921.0]}, {'...     [1067.0, 921.0...]
2   2020-02-27 15:36:52     [{'values': [776.0]}, {'values': [826.0, 938.0..      [776.0, 826.0, 938.0...]

IN:
print(df_sim.loc[0, "rr_list"])

OUT:
[727.0, 693.0, 688.0, 689.0, 699.0]
```

I tried applying the best answer from my last question, which recommended using list comprehension

```
for i in df_sim.index:
    df_sim.loc[i, "rr_list"] = [val for sub_dict in df_sim.loc[i, "rrintervals"] for val in sub_dict['values']]
```

But I kept getting a `ValueError`:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-152-c50bd1585f57> in <module>
      1 for i in df_sim.index:
----> 2     df_sim.loc[i, "rr_list"] = [val for sub_dict in df_sim.loc[i, "rrintervals"] for val in sub_dict['values']]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
    668             key = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
    669         indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
--> 670         self._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)
    671 
    672     def _validate_key(self, key, axis: int):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _setitem_with_indexer(self, indexer, value)
   1015                     if len(labels) != len(value):
   1016                         raise ValueError(
-> 1017                             "Must have equal len keys and value "
   1018                             "when setting with an iterable"
   1019                         )

ValueError: Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hah. I found what I was looking for just moments after posting this.

I created an empty `list` outside of my `for` loop, populated it with the results of list comprehension, and then assigned the populated list to a new column.

```
rr_list = []
for i in df_sim.index:
    rr_list.append([val for sub_dict in df_sim.loc[i, "rrintervals"] for val in sub_dict['values']])

df_sim["rr_list"] = rr_list
```

I'm open to alternative answers!

Answer (score 1):

Your solution seems fine.
If you want a one-liner:

```
df['rr_list'] = df['rrintervals'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame.from_records(x).sum())
```